# Why onClick in my React class is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Below is my React Component

```
var NavHead = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return { in: 0};
    },

    handleClicking: function(event){
        var text=0;
        console.log(this.state.in);
    },


    render: function(){
        return(

            <div className="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a className="navbar-brand" href={this.props.url} >
                    <img src={this.props.img_src} alt="tm-logo" onClick={this.handleClicking}/>
                </a>

            </div>

        );
    }
});
```

However, when I click the logo, there is nothing happened. Is there anything wrong in my code?

For more information, I have more than 20 components in my file. I have tried to copy-paste onClick handler to every component, and found that there is only 1 component that the code works. Below is that component.

```
var NavBarMenu = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { itemClick: 0};
    },

    handleClick: function(event) {
       console.log(this.state.itemClick)
       this.setState({itemClick: event.currentTarget.dataset.id});
    },


    render: function(){


        return(

            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-menu">
                {this.props.data.map(function(object, i){

                    return  <li onClick={this.handleClick} data-id={i} className={this.state.itemClick==i?"active":""}><a href={object.url}>{object.name}</a></li>;
                },this)}
            </ul>

        );
    }

});
```

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the console?

Comment: There is an error message here.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' of undefined

Comment: If you google that error you should get some results about React not being defined. Are you using CD. Links or are you in an npm-like environment?  If it is the latter have you required/imported The correct React libraries?

Comment: I believe that I have include react, react-dom, and babel-core correctly. However, such error still be shown. I might start to create component again one-by-one to see the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code, and run into the same issue.
I fixed it by changing the order of required react js files. The react-dom.js library was included before react.js

Something similar to:

```
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
```

The key thing is `react-dom.js` should come after `react.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript engine is optimizing out your code in the first case because it is only doing a console.log. In the second case, state is mutated so the code is kept around.

Comment: I'm curios about the first part. Should such optimization happen? After all there is code that actually does something (logging to console) and assuming there is no `NODE_ENV='production'` (in some cases even when there is) it's potentially as valuable as everything else.

Comment: I have tried to modify the state value (in the first component). Again, there is nothing happen.